# AWS EC2のユーザをIAMで一元管理したい

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

▼ 環境
・EC2は4台あり、OSはAmazon Linux2である。

▼ したいこと
・IAMで作成したユーザでEC2にログインしたい。
・EC2のサーバごとにユーザを作成したりするのがすごく手間だし、
　個別で管理するのが難しいため、IAM上で全てのEC2ユーザを管理できれば便利だと思ったため。

▼ 試したこと
・IAMでユーザ作成し、EC2 FullAccessのロールをアタッチ（インスタンスにもアタッチ）
・AWS CodeCommitのSSHキーを登録し、IAMのユーザ名と公開鍵で接続を試すも接続不可

▼ 質問内容
・EC2の複数台サーバのユーザーをIAMで一元管理することは可能でしょうか。
・また、こちらはAWS内だけで完結できますでしょうか。

「このサービス使うとできますよ」的なアドバイスを頂けると嬉しいです。
できないならできないで、皆様はどのようにユーザ管理されているかなども教えて欲しいです。

Comment: ちゃんと読んでませんが近そう https://cloudonaut.io/manage-aws-ec2-ssh-access-with-iam/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hinaloe さんのコメントや、 ksaito さんの回答を参考に、以下の方針で可能そうです。

#### 方針

- AuthorizedKeysCommand を利用する。
- authorized_keys_command から実行されるプログラムの中で aws コマンドで iam から pubkey を読み込む

AuthorizedKeysCommand とは何かというと、 authorized_keys を file に記述するのではなく、プログラムの標準出力でもって指定できる sshd の設定オプションです。

また、 IAM ユーザーは、 ssh の public key をひもづけることができます。これは、主に CodeCommit で用いられますが、今回はこれを上手く利用できるので、これを活用します。

手元では検証できていないですが、これをやることで、各ユーザーが、それぞれの IAM ユーザー名で ssh すると、その IAM ユーザーにひもづいた ssh の公開鍵でもって認証が行われるようになるはずだ、と思っています。

#### やりかた(未検証)

/etc/ssh/ssh_config に以下を記述する

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /etc/ssh/iam-key-finder
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

/etc/ssh/iam-key-finder を作成する。 root:root で、 755 で作成しておく。

```
for key_id in $(aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name "$1" --query 'SSHPublicKeys[].SSHPublicKeyId' --output text)
do
    aws iam get-ssh-public-key --encoding SSH --user-name "$1" --ssh-public-key-id $key_id --query 'SSHPublicKey.SSHPublicKeyBody' --output text
done
```

ログインしたいユーザーたちを、対象 ec2 ホスト上で作成しておく。

対象 ec2 に instance profile を指定し、 iam list-ssh-public-keys と get-ssh-public-key の実行権限を与える。

Answer (score 1):

IAMユーザにアップロードしたssh公開鍵をaws cliで参照して$HOME/.sshに設定する方法はどうでしょうか。

IAMユーザにSSH公開鍵は登録済みということですので、下記の一連のコマンドで登録済みのSSH公開鍵が取得できます。
この例では、`iam-user1`というIAMユーザのSSH公開鍵を取得します。

```
$ IAMUSER=iam-user1
$ KEYID=$(aws iam list-ssh-public-keys --user-name $IAMUSER --query 'SSHPublicKeys[].SSHPublicKeyId' --output text)
$ aws iam get-ssh-public-key --encoding SSH --user-name $IAMUSER --ssh-public-key-id $KEYID --query 'SSHPublicKey.SSHPublicKeyBody' --output text
ssh-rsa AAAA...
$
```

これを$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keysに登録します。